# ¿Como limitar un input fyle a máximo 3mb?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tengo un formulario donde subo multiples archivos pdf en un input file, lo cual limito la cantidad máxima de archivos a 3 y ahora quisiera que cada documento me limitara que no exceda los 3mb por archivo.

Este es mi código:

```
 <div class="input-group">
   <input id="subirPDFinput" type="file" name="expArchivo[]" accept="application/pdf" multiple="multiple" required>
 </div>
<script>
  if ($(this)[0].files[0].type != "application/pdf") {
        alert("You can select only 2 images");
    }
</script>

<script>
    $("#subirPDFinput").on("change", function() {
        if ($("#subirPDFinput")[0].files.length > 3) {
            swal.fire({
                icon: "info",
                title: "!Solo se permite 3 archivos como maximo!",
                showConfirmButton: false,
                timer: 1500
            }).then(function(result) {
                $miInput.value = "";

            })
            $("#subirPDFinput").val("");
        } else {}
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Que tal JMM, tienes que validarlo con la propiedad size de los elementos almacenados en files. Te dejo este enlace el cual te va ayudar a resolverlo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717793/javascript-file-upload-size-validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer la validación con JavaScript, te dejo un ejemplo

```
// Tamaño maximo del archivo
const maxSize = 3000000; 

// Obtener referencia al elemento
const $miInput = document.querySelector("#subirPDFinput");

$miInput.addEventListener("change", function () {
    // si no hay archivos, regresamos
    if (this.files.length <= 0) return;

    // Validamos el primer archivo únicamente
    const archivo = this.files[0];
    if (archivo.size > maxSize) {
        const tamanioEnMb = maxSize / 1000000;
        alert(`El tamaño máximo es ${tamanioEnMb} MB`);
        // Limpiar
        $miInput.value = "";
    } else {
        // Validación pasada. Envía el formulario o haz lo que tengas que hacer
    }
});
```